# How do I create a SQL query that groups in certain percent range

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create a SQL query that groups the increase price of items in certain percentage range. For example

2 items increased between 0 to 10 %

4 items increased between 10 to 20%

2 items increased between 20 to 30%

...

Target Server: MySQL

Comment: Some clue about the database schema? It is difficult to imagine your tables and from where do you need to extract the prices or ranges...

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN PercentChange >= 0 AND PercentChange <= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0) END AS ZeroTen,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PercentChange > 10 AND PercentChange <= 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0) END AS TenTwenty,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PercentChange > 20 AND PercentChange <= 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0) END AS TwentyThirty
    FROM MagicChangeTable
```

Note: `MagicChangeTable` may in fact be a subquery to calculate the percent change.

Comment: In what group 10 % or 20 % (exactly) go is ambiguous in the question. But it must be `PercentChange >= 0` in any case.

Comment: @Joe This will work, however what would be the most efficient way to obtain the ranges 0 to 10. 10 to 10 and so on depending what it was calculated?? Is it possible to make the grouping dynamically?? by calculating on the fly the ranges depending on the percentages?? Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

If You want all ranges by 10:
Use:

```
SELECT (d-10)*10 AS `from` , (d-9)*10 AS `to` , c AS `count` FROM 
   (SELECT DISTINCT(FLOOR((`p`.`new`*10)/(`p`.`old`))) AS d,
      count(1) AS c FROM prices as p GROUP BY 1) AS stats
```

for such structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `prices` (
  `old` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `new` int(11) NOT NULL
);
```

edit: >=from and < to